# Hibernate Envers can't resolve audit table

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework, hibernate-criteria, hibernate-envers

I have a JPA entity which I want audited. I added Envers to my project, and added the `@Audited` annotation to the entities I need. Now, the changes are being logged in the audit tables, but I cannot retrieve them through the audit readers provided by Envers.

My entity is as follows.

```
@Entity
@Audited
@AuditTable(value = "blog_posts_AUD")
@Table(name = "blog_posts")
public class Post {
...
}
```

I'm trying to query the audit tables as follows.

```
AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
List revisions = reader.getRevisions(Post.class, primaryKey);
```

This fails, because the SQL call contains a reference to a table called `org.foo.bar.blog_posts_AUD`, which obviously does not exist. It seems that Hibernate is not picking up the `@AuditTable` annotation (or the default audit table suffix, for that matter). Anyone ever faced this before?

Comment: I assume it works if you don't use the `@AuditTable` annotation.  From what I can see based on what you posted both scenarios should work and its likely a bug.  Open an issue at https://hibernate.atlassian.net for hibernate-envers and attach a test case example.

Comment: Doesn't work even if I remove `@AuditTable`.

Comment: The table Envers should create would be called `blog_posts_AUD` assuming you're using the default configuration for the suffix.  At no point should the SQL query attempt to reference a table called `org.foo.bar.blog_posts_AUD`.  Can you replicate the problem with the envers test case templates at https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates?  Just fork the repository, use the `envers-5` test and add your entities and such and open a jira attaching the envers test case.